# Displaying image from path returns about:Blank

Tags: php, html, image, apache

I have a bunch of jpg images in a folder that I need to call up one at a time. The user looks up a number, the number pulls up a filename from a database, and the filename is appended to a path to make a valid image path. That path is then placed in the src tag of an html element. The problem: nothing shows up except the little 16x16 image error thing. When I open it in a new tab, it says "about:Blank". I've echoed the path on its own to make sure it's showing up properly, and I've tried calling up the image in an independent html element with the full path placed in the src tag. What's going on here?

```
<?php //Location
function Location($JobID) {
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','******','testdb1')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
    $JobID = $_POST['JobID'];
    $getinfo = "SELECT Location FROM Jobs WHERE JobID = '$JobID'";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $getinfo);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $Location = $row['Location'];
    echo "<img src=C:/wamp64/www/Floormaps/".$Location.">";
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're doing this on a web page that resides in the root of your web directory try changing your image tag to `"<img src='Floormap/$Location'>";`

Comment: Looks like your quotes are incorrect. Try this: `echo '<img src="C:/wamp64/www/Floormaps/' . $Location . '">';`

Comment: @Dave,  that worked! Thanks!

Comment: Great .... would appreciate it if you would accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this on a web page that resides in the root of your web directory try changing your image tag as shown below. The web server only needs to know where the image is in relationship to the page where the source tag is.

```
<?php //Location
function Location($JobID) {
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','******','testdb1')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
    $JobID = $_POST['JobID'];
    $getinfo = "SELECT Location FROM Jobs WHERE JobID = '$JobID'";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $getinfo);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $Location = $row['Location'];
    echo "<img src='Floormap/$Location'>";
}
?>
```